# Latex beamer verbatim problem with \end{frame} in TeXLive 2017

Tags: beamer, verbatim

The following MWE does not compile with beamer 2017/07/13 v3.42 from TeXLive 2017-20170807:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \begin{verbatim}
    \end{frame}
  \end{verbatim}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The problem only occurs when `\end{frame}` is used within the verbatim environment, despite the use of `[fragile]`. A different text does not cause the problem. The error produced by lualatex is the following:

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim.
```

However, an older version (e.g. 3.36) of latex beamer from TeXLive 2016-20160801 does compile the MWE correctly without errors.

Further investigation showed that it looks like a regression from commit `0c387de` (Fix for github issue #326).

Comment: This only used to work in an old version by accident because scanning for `\end{frame}` in a `fragile` slide was broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`beamer` just scans ahead for `\end{frame}`, so you cannot use `\end{frame}` inside verbatim inside a `frame`.  This is also documented:

> [image]

But there is a workaround, which is also documented:

> [image]

Applied to your specific example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newenvironment{fragileframe}%
  {\begin{frame}[fragile,environment=fragileframe]}%
  {\end{frame}}

\begin{document}
\begin{fragileframe}
  \begin{verbatim}
    \end{frame}
  \end{verbatim}
\end{fragileframe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The accidental support of older versions was a bit misleading and I didn't look into that direction to find a solution.